# html5 application cache joomla website

Tags: html, joomla, web, pageload, application-cache

we build multiple websites for our clients based on a Joomla installation we have customised.

We have to support back to ie7 but I would like to start making these websites available offline. Do people think this is a good idea seeing as this is not an application?

Also how do people feel this would work with content that would be changing on a semi regular basis?

I welcome your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should note that any offline functionality you implement using `AppCache` will only be available to IE users with version 10 or greater ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=application%20cache)).

Despite the name, making websites (as well as web applications) available offline is very much a valid use case of `AppCache`.

There's a good introduction to the subject [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) and an excellent article [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/application-cache-is-a-douchebag/), including the rationale for using the technology and the gotchas encountered in doing so, from a guy who used `AppCache` extensively in a recent project.